# Scrollviewer and scroll direction (Vertical vs. Horizontal)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like a textblock that has vertical scrolling.  I have the following XAML

```
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" Margin="10,416,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="463" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True" >
        <TextBlock Name="txtConfigPath" Text="" >                
        </TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

This produces a textblock that only scrolls horizontally.  I've tried everything I can think of but this control only wants to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options here. You can set `TextWrapping=Wrap` on the `TextBlock` and `Disable` the HorizontalScrolling on the `ScrollViewer`, or you can set the `TextWrapping` on the TextBlock and either set a fixed width to your `TextBlock` or you can Bind it's `MaxWidth` to the `ActualWidth` of the `ScrollViewer` like `TextBlock MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}, Path=ActualWidth}"`

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Add a grid with a row definition of * to accommodate your ScrollViewer and Auto for other rows (as for Header and footer.)
Add this code for the ScrollViewer:

```
<UserControl ...>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock><Run Text="Some text"/></TextBlock>

    <ScrollViewer 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        CanContentScroll="True" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
        MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, 
            BindsDirectlyToSource=True, 
            ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}">
```